# How to return image

Tags: php, image, mime-types, show

I want to show image with php script. Here is my current code:

```
<?php
if (isset ($_GET['id'])) $id = $_GET['id'];
$t=getimagesize ($id) or die('Unknown type of image');

switch ($t[2])
{
    case 1:
    $type='GIF';
    $img=imagecreatefromgif($path);
    break;
    case 2:
    $type='JPEG';
    $img=imagecreatefromjpeg($path);
    break;
    case 3:
    $type='PNG';
    $img=imagecreatefrompng($path);
    break;
}

header("Content-type: image/".$type);
echo $img;
?>
```

But it doesn't show the image. What is the right way instead of `echo $img`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
imagejpeg($img);
```

Comment: `
Warning: imagejpeg(): supplied argument is not a valid Image resource` to the second line of your code

Comment: The question asks about **return** image... IMHO, the answer of this guy is the way to go: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22266402/how-to-encode-an-image-resource-to-base64)... that combined with this another [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html) must do the job.

Answer (score 4):

just like this :

```
public function getImage()
{

    $imagePath ="img/wall_1.jpg";

    $image = file_get_contents(imagePath );
            header('content-type: image/gif');
            echo $image;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are functions for each format.

- PNG: imagepng http://php.net/imagepng
- JPEG: imagejpeg http://php.net/imagejpeg
- GIF: imagegif http://php.net/imagegif

In your case you could add:

```
switch ($t[2])
{
    case 1:
    imagegif($img);
    break;
    case 2:
    imagejpeg($img);
    break;
    case 3:
    imagepng($img);
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used `echo()` for this before and it's worked. But try using `imagejpeg()` function instead.

Also, make sure you don't have any other content being output either before or after the image in your script. A common problem is blank spaces and line feeds being output caused by space and line feeds before or after the `<?php` and `?>` tags. You need to remove all of these. And check any other PHP code loaded via `include()` or `requre()` for the same thing.