# How to display Base64 images in HTML

Tags: html, image, base64

I'm having trouble displaying a Base64 image inline.

How can I do it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Display Image</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img style='display:block; width:100px;height:100px;' id='base64image'
       src='data:image/jpeg;base64, LzlqLzRBQ... <!-- Base64 data -->' />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs

Comment: Does the image extension matter in the src

Comment: To anyone reading this question and its answers... consider whether or not you actually need base64 encoding.  There is almost never need for this in modern browsers.  If you use base64 encoding, you're adding 33% overhead to the size of the image, additional CPU and memory requirements both when encoding and decoding, cluttering up the DOM with extra data that doesn't need to be there, and imposing stringent and inconsistent limits on sizes and resource types.  Use blobs, object URLs, etc. instead.

Comment: @Brad sometimes when you need things to be self-contained, Base64 is the only option. I actually came across this page while trying to write a script to extract images from a Jupyter notebook (which saves them as Base64 PNGs) into an HTML file to be published as a report.

Comment: @vikarjramun Sounds like you have literally the only case I've read on Stack Overflow in, several years, where you have a legitimate use case.  In which case, yes, by all means, use what you need.  :-)

Comment: @Brad there's certainly a better way to do what I'm doing, but I'm lazy and don't care about presentation now since this is just to send to my colleauges to discuss. Besides, who doesn't love writing complex shell one-liners to accomplish their tasks? :)

Comment: Base 64 encoded images are used often when the web-master tries preventing image download. Some JS depending on the cursor position for instance, generates an url to a part of an image, or a full image encoded in BASE64, and therefore not cached as an image, or listed as an image object of the page. Either, it can not be read without master script pulling it as an image object. Now I have such a website in front of me and don't have an idea how to pull these images out. I can see them even in Mozilla debugger, downloaded on jQuery event, and changing content every time I move the mouse.

Comment: @Brad Another case of needing base64 is when using some kind of image uploader/selector of some kind on the client side, wherein the user chooses an image form their device and then we want to see it on screen immediately. The only place it exists at that point is within the browser, so, as far as I'm aware, base64 is the way to go.

Comment: @StuartAitken No, that's demonstrably incorrect.  We have had object URLs for nearly a decade.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL  Please read up on this, and go back to anyone who has told you that this is an appropriate use of base64 and spread the good news that base64 is not necessary for this use case.

Comment: @Brad Haha, that's excellent, thank you. Gotta say, that's a surprisingly hidden little feature. It's genuinely the first time I've seen it.

Comment: There are a lot more than just a few use cases for base64 and telling people to avoid base64 instead of teaching them the proper methods seems a huge fail to me. base64 is perfectly fine except it can't be cached if used inline, so instead try to keep its usage inside css files so the css file is cached containing the base 64. 

Its also useful when you have CORS policies that use custom headers with cross server calls, to just hand someone back a base64 than a url to an image they can't access unless they set headers... meaning a simple `<img src="https://url/path"> is never going to work.

Comment: In HTML the quotes to use are "" not ''.

Comment: For what it's worth to the OP or others. I was having issues displaying the data in a jpeg format and this post helped me find out I was encoding already encoded data. The base64 values in the OP's code is double encoded as well. The beginning of my jpeg data was also `LzlqLzRBQ...`. After correcting the mistake,  it looked more like `/9j/4AAQSk...` and solved the issue.

Comment: @Brad, I am confused by your comments.  You seem to be arguing against Base64, as if we have some alternative when we need the image to be contained within the HTML file itself -- especially in your first comment.  I have looked at your link regarding object URLs and made no sense of it.  "Blob" sounds like a very generic term to me.  Is there an option other than Base64, or was your response to vikarjramun meant as a retraction of your previous comment?

Comment: @RichardB Folks use base64 when they don't need to, all the time.  If you actually do *require* putting the resource in your HTML, then yes, it needs to be base64 encoded, and has all of the drawbacks that I listed above.  Regarding blob URLs and what not, this comment was directed to folks using resources dragged in by the user.  Everyone thinks they need base64 for this, and they don't.  Blob isn't a generic term.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob

Comment: @Brad, the fact that in a particular context something has a particular meaning does not mean that it isn't a generic term.  It is still just a generic term that has a particular meaning as one of many things people might be getting at.

The context for this question is HTML, a document markup language.  Your links seem to refer to some language that is not mentioned anywhere in the post to which you are responding, not even in the tags.  I find them to be off-topic, a digression from the post in order for you to express a personal opinion that seems to be outside the scope of this post.

Comment: @Brad, I am critiquing your first comment, not just your reply.  To assume that javascript is the relevant programming language just because html is used as the markup language is extremely arrogant.  Blob might have a particular meaning in Javascript, but you use it in your first comment, and neither that comment nor that to which it replies mentions javascript at all.

Comment: @Brad, I had already read the specific comments.  You should try reading the bible.  *caugh* *cuagh*.

Comment: using base64 can be convenient some times even when unnecessary. 33% image size is not that big of a deal most of the time, in the grand scheme of things

Answer (score 1711, accepted):

My suspect is of course the actual Base64 data. Otherwise it looks good to me. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hpP45/) where a similar scheme is working. You may try specifying the character set.

```html
<div>
  <p>Taken from wikpedia</p>
  <img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
    AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
        9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
</div>
```

You can try [this Base64 decoder](https://www.base64decode.org/) to see if your Base64 data is correct or not.

Comment: thankyou for taking the time to answer my question... that js fiddle simply outputs a red dot?? is that what it is meant to do?

Comment: @Christopher, yes - its a data URI for a red dot image (source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme). I am just pointing out that there is no apparent issue in what you are doing except perhaps actual base64 data. Use the given decoder and save decoded binary data as an jpeg file and try to open it. If it does not work then there is an issue in your base64 encoding.

Comment: I believe I have discovered the problem is when the base64 file is being uploaded every "+" seems to be removed. Which intern nullifies the jpeg. I am posting the image from a device to the server with AJAX is it possible that "+" is not passed correctly throught because it is a htmlentity?

Comment: @Christopher, "+" character can be problematic in post data. See this related SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373414/ajax-post-and-plus-sign-how-to-encode

Comment: Just used the HTML from the question above with some valid base64 data for a PNG and it works fine ... this is the correct answer.

Comment: @VinayC am getting huge encoding code for my small circle..is there any way to reduce the code..?

Comment: @VenuMadhav, Base64 encoded size is approx 1.37 times of original data. So, check your image data and how can you reduce the same (e.g. using small size image say 16x16, png encoded etc.).

Comment: Beware that data URI images will be blocked by some Antivirus solutions

Comment: is this  a best practice?

Comment: <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($image).'" style="width:200px">

Comment: base64_encode($image) is left

Answer (score 153):

You need to specify the correct *Content-type*, *Content-encoding* and *charset*.

Like

```
 data:image/jpeg;charset=utf-8;base64,
```

according to the syntax of the [data URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Syntax):

```
 data:[<media type>][;charset=<character set>][;base64],<data>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13265902/http-content-encoding-base64 suggests there's no header for encoding the HTTP body using base-64.

Comment: Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285372/is-content-transfer-encoding-an-http-header - it's a MIME header, not an HTTP one. Can you expand on how exactly the content-encoding should be specified?

Comment: This solved the problem for me. Chrome would assume UTF-8 and show the images while Microsoft Edge would simply fail to render. Once I included the charset the images showed perfectly.

Comment: Is it possible to use `input` instead of `img`? I want to show the value on the label or textbox, instead of an image.

Answer (score 68):

First convert your image to Base64 (encode to Base64). You can do it online or with a PHP script.

After converting you will get the result as

```
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
```

Now it's simple to use.

You have to just put it in the `src` of the image and define it there as it is in Base64-encoded form.

Example:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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">
```

Comment: Excellent solution to an iOS UIWebView cache problem that kept referencing old image data even if I deleted the image files.  This answer helped me to avoid creating unique file names and having to clean-up afterwards.  Thank you @NARGIS PARWEEN

Comment: Is this an image encoded to a string? Can every image be represented as a string? The more detail an image has the longer the string?

Comment: @Timo yes (here with "base64"), yes (I believe any data can be string encoded), and yes (the more data, the more characters).

Comment: Convert your image file to base64 in PowerShell https://deangrant.me/2014/10/01/encoding-image-files-into-a-base64-string-using-powershell/

Comment: `iVBORw0` means `PNG` in base64 language

Answer (score 56):

If you have PHP on the back-end, you can use this code:

```php
$image = 'http://images.itracki.com/2011/06/favicon.png';
// Read image path, convert to base64 encoding
$imageData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($image));

// Format the image SRC:  data:{mime};base64,{data};
$src = 'data: ' . mime_content_type($image) . ';base64,' . $imageData;

// Echo out a sample image
echo '<img src="' . $src . '">';
```

Answer (score 26):

This will show an image of Base64 data:

```
<style>
    .logo {
        width: 290px;
        height: 63px;
        background: url(data:image/png;base64,copy-paste-Base64-data-here) no-repeat;
    }
</style>

<div class="logo"></div>
```

Comment: I think this needs an explanation of how it answers the question. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34149566/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 22):

It is very simple.

Programing base64 images manually are (almost) impossible so there is a web application to do that. Here is the link for the app: https://www.opinionatedgeek.com/codecs/base64decoder (The decoder works for both regular and URL-safe encodings, and it can decode or encode your text/doc)

As you say, it starts with `data:image/jpeg;base64,`.
Below is an example is taken from Wikipedia, but it is only an example.

```html
<div>
  <img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
    AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
        9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
</div>
```

I know it just outputs a red dot, but it can be useful when you don't have enough space to include the images or something like that.

The only problem is that this type of encoding is very long, it can be like 20 lines.
Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 20):

Add Base64 data:

```html
<img src="data:image/png;base64,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">
```

or

In JavaScript

```
var id = document.getElementById("image");

id.src = base64Url;
```

Comment: Why is JavaScript required?

Comment: javascript is not neccessary ,if u have static base64 url.you dirctly put into src

Answer (score 10):

You can put your data directly in a `url` statement, like:

```
src = 'url(imageData)';
```

And to get the image data you can use the PHP function:

```
$imageContent = file_get_contents("imageDir/" . $imgName);

$imageData = base64_encode($imageContent);
```

So you can copy paste the value of imageData and paste it directly to your URL and assign it to the `src` attribute of your image.

Comment: But in the end it comes out as HTML. What *is* the HTML output?

Answer (score 10):

Try this one too:

```
let base64="iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==";
let buffer=Uint8Array.from(atob(base64), c => c.charCodeAt(0));
let blob=new Blob([buffer], { type: "image/gif" });
let url=URL.createObjectURL(blob);
let img=document.createElement("img");
img.src=url;
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

**Not recommended for production as it is only compatible with modern browsers.**

Comment: What is this? JavaScript? TypeScript? In what context does this code run?

Comment: @PeterMortensen It's just plain JavaScript (with some ES6 syntax). You can run it anywhere. e.g. paste it in Chrome DevTools console, in HTML script tag, or in a .js file

Answer (score 10):

You can display a Base64 image in HTML by setting the src attribute of an  element to data:image/[image format];base64,[Base64 data].

In this example, the data:image/jpeg;base64, part of the src attribute specifies the format of the image (JPEG) and the LzlqLzRBQ... part is the Base64 data of the image.

The style attribute of the  element can be used to specify the display and size properties of the image. In this case, display:block will make the image a block-level element and width:100px;height:100px; sets the width and height of the image to 100 pixels.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Display Base64 Image</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
    AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
        9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" />
  </body>
</html>
```

The  tag has its src attribute set to `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO 9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==`. This specifies that the image is a PNG format and the Base64 data is included after the base64, part of the src attribute.

Answer (score 8):

The + character occurring in a data URI should be encoded as %2B. This is like encoding any other string in a URI. For example, argument separators (? and &) must be encoded when a URI with an argument is sent as part of another URI.

Answer (score 5):

It seems there is some error in your data URL.

You can use this online [Base64 encode](http://base64online.org/encode/) / [Base64 decode tool](http://base64online.org/decode/) to encode your images for embedding:
http://base64online.org/encode/

Check "Format as Data URL" option to format base64 data as URL.

Answer (score 1):

Storing Base64-image as a variable and display it using plain HTML and JavaScript:

```
<img id="image"/>
<script>
var ticket = {
            "validationDataValidDate": "2019-05-30",
            "validationImage": "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"
        };
document.querySelectorAll('[id="image"]')[0].src = 'data:image/png;base64, '+ticket["validationImage"];
</script>
```

[Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/punnerud/hctkxy1d/2/), to try it directly.

Answer (score 1):

An old question, but I discovered something about this.

If you load an image using Pillow(PIL) and use base64.b64encode(img.tobytes()), then the Base64 code is invalid.

To get this to work, once your bytes are loaded into an Image class, Create a BytesIO object and then use this to save the image with the format to the BytesIO, i.e img.save(bt_ob, format="png").

Set seak to 0 and then use the output of the BytesIO object to create the Base64 encoded text

```
base64.b64encode(bt_ob.read()).decode()
```

This code will now work in the html in the "data:image/png;base64,<>" format.

Thus the html will only work on encoded data from a file like object, and a Pillow Image object doesn't produce that and so doesn't work